# AngularJS ng-click not invoked with {{$index}} used

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For some reason AngularJS does not fire off the event when {{$index}} is used in ng-click.

**My html:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="foo in foos">
     <label>{{foo.name}}</label>
     <a href="#" ng-click="remove({{$index}})">X (doesnt work)</a>
     <a href="#" ng-click="remove(0)">Remove first element (works)</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lcasg/3/

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: This specific example is addressed on the Angular 'expression' page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The value of the ng-click attribute is evaluated as an angular expression, so simply use `remove($index)`.

Comment: ahh i thought that didn't work. Maybe because its rendered as remove($index) and I assume it won't work. Thanks heaps!!

Comment: Can you give an example of this?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign, bring up Adrian's fiddle, and make the change I suggest: `<a href="#" ng-click="remove($index)">X (works now!)</a>`.

Answer (score 3):

solved!

```
<div ng-repeat="idiomax in textos.idiomas ">
    <div class="idioma"  ng-click="cambiaridioma($index)" ng-class="idioma != $index || 'idioma-activo'" > 
    {{idiomax.idioma}}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$scope.cambiaridioma = function (indice) {
        $scope.idioma = indice;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `$index` in a string expression and this is how it worked:

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="showUserStories($event, '#modal-id-prefix-' + $index)">Show Modal</button>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.showUserStories = function(event, modalId) {
        $(modalId).modal("show");
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```