# ng-click not setting $location.path() when path is dynamic

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use a tag like this:

```
<a ng-click="$location.path('/restaurant/{{restaurant._id}}')">{{restaurant.name}}</a>
```

However, nothing happens when I click the  tag.

Oddly, if I hard-code the value there, like this:

```
<a ng-click="$location.path('/restaurant/512ad624b67fe1f446709331')">{{restaurant.name}}</a>
```

it works as expected.

Screenshot of the DOM:

[image]

Why would this be? How could I work around this?

Comment: Can you make a JsFiddle that demonstrates this?

Comment: Can you try with `$location.path('/restaurant/' + restaurant.id)`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596235/angularjs-ng-click-not-invoked-with-index-used

Comment: Oooh! That works! If you want to answer as a question, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Not "answer as a question" -- but you know what I mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [AngularJS ng-click not invoked with {{$index}} used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596235/angularjs-ng-click-not-invoked-with-index-used), you are able to use the variable directly, without braces.

I.e.

```
<a ng-click="$location.path('/restaurant/' + restaurant._id)">{{restaurant.name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
    $scope.doTheNeedful = function(country){
        var newPath = "home/";
        newPath += country;
        $location.path(newPath);
    }
```