# Attach a parameter from Angular after a path in window.location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, href, window.location

I have an html file that show a dynamic table using an Angular script:

```html
<h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;">Elenco macchinette</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="thetable">
                
             
                <tr> 
                    <th class="th2">Id</th> 
                    <th class="th2">Data Creazione</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Categoria</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Capacità</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Area geografica</th>  
                    <th class="th2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Attivo&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>  
                    
             </tr> 
             
              
      
                
                <tr ng-repeat="dispensercategory in dispensercategories">  
                 
          
            <td onclick="window.location='#showemp/{{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }}'"> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }}</td>  
            <td> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.creationDate }}</td>
            <td> {{ dispensercategory.category.description }}</td>  
            <td> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.capacity.type }}</td>  
            <td> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.geoArea.city }}</td>  
            <td> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.stateOn }}</td>  
    

            </tr>  
          
            </table>
              
              
    <h2 class="sub-header" style="color:#4e67c3;">Dipendenti macchinette</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="thetable">
                
             
                <tr> 
                    <th class="th2">Nome</th> 
                    <th class="th2">Cognome</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Data di nascita</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Telefono</th>  
                    <th class="th2">Id macchinetta</th>   
                    
             </tr> 
             
              
      
                
                <tr ng-repeat="staffdispenser in staffdispensers">  
                 
          
            <td onclick="window.location='#/showemp'"> {{ staffdispenser.staff.name }}</td>  
            <td> {{ staffdispenser.staff.surname }}</td>
            <td> {{ staffdispenser.staff.birthDate }}</td>  
            <td> {{ staffdispenser.staff.phone }}</td>  
            <td> {{ staffdispenser.dispenser.iddispenser }}</td>   
    

            </tr>  
          
            </table>
              
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="scripts/rest-services.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main-admin.js"></script>
 
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript"></script>
```

I want to attach a parameter in this line:

```
<td onclick="window.location='#showemp/{{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }}'"> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }}</td>
```

I want to attach the value of  `{{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }}` to the url `#showemp/`. But in this way it doesn't read the value of Angular variable, but it read url such a unique string:

```
http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/fddWebapp/fixed_admin.html#/showemp/%7B%7B%20dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser%20%7D%7D
```

Look this:

[image]

When I click on the cell of "1", I want to go to "#/showemp1".
How can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you not using `ng-click`

Comment: you can use `$location` service instead of  `window.location` `$location.path('#showemp/').search({your param: 'dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser'});`

Comment: mmm, I did not know existed. I can use it to the html file without call a script?

Comment: yes try inside`ng-click="$location.path('#showemp/').search({your param: 'dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser'});"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) instead of `window.location`
This could be achieve in few ways

```
ng-click="$location.path('#showemp/').search({your param: 'dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser'});"
```

or use

```
 ng-click="$location.path('#showemp/'+{{dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser}})"
```

or

**In controller**

```
yourApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.changePath= function(param){
        $location.url('/#showemp/'+param);
        //optional use if not work $scope.$apply();
    };
});
```

**In HTML**

```
ng-click="changePath(dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser)"
```

Comment: Nothing happens if I use:  <td ng-click="$location.path('#showemp/').search({id: 'dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser'});">

Maybe I need to import some functions in js file?

Comment: no need to import external js file it bundle with angularjs.try this then `ng-click="$location.path('/#showemp/'+ {{dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser);"` Note:There can be a syntax errors in my code.

Comment: Make an error:

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 29 of the expression [$location.path('#showemp/'+{{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }})] starting at [{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }})].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=29&p3=%24location.path('<td ng-click="$location.path('#showemp/'+{{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }})">howemp%2F'%2B%7B%7B%dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser%20%7D%7D)&p4=%7B%dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser%20%7D%7D)

Comment: I also use the response in this page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215219/ng-click-not-setting-location-path-when-path-is-dynamic

But nothing happenens, zero errors in this case

Comment: or use  `ng-click="$location.url('/#showemp/' + {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }});"`

Comment: redirected in this url: http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/fddWebapp/fixed_admin.html#/#showemp%2Fdispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser

dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser must be 1..read it such a string

Comment: remove "" on dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ng-href` directive, and do the following:

```
<td>
    <a ng-href="#showemp/{{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }}"> {{ dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser }} </a>
</td>
```

Comment: It works, but I prefer to allow to click on the cell, not only on the text